# How to break iteration in nested loop to make array of arrays?

Tags: node.js

I would like to break the iteration of the inner loop so that only the length of the inner loop is pushed into the array and then added all over again to create an array of arrays

```
  for (let i = 0; i < attrcol1.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < attrcol1[i].length; j++) {
      let a = attrcol1[i][j];
      let ob = Object.values(a)[0];
      pushed.push(ob);
      if(j == attrcol1[i].length) break;

      
    }
  
  }
```

Comment: could you provide an example of expected result ?

Comment: @AndangSudrajat I would like the inner loop to push to an array of values in attrcol1 [i] .length, close the array, and then create another array in the next sequence still limiting itself to the number that is currently in the inner loop